# Get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when run Page Inspector on MVC app in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

When I try to run an MVC web application in Page Inspector mode I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and the app just hangs.

Microsoft has noted that it's a bug but doesn't say when they'll fix it.

Anybody have a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any more information regarding the error?

Comment: Does the view display correctly when you run the application? Have you updated Visual Studio to Update 2?

Comment: I am having the issue.  I am running VS2012 with Update 2. I am attempting to debug a VB.Net 4.0 web application.  It works just fine in a debugger.

Comment: Having same issue. Running VS2012 with Update 2.
Tried devenv.exe /ResetSettings but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_pageinspector_topic2.aspx?ppud=4 I believe the problem is:

> The Page Inspector window will show the /Home/Index URL mapped to the source View you selected.

We changed our routing away from /Home/Index a long time ago.  If I create a new Web application, which has a /Home/Index page, then Page Inspector works fine.

So, long story short, always make sure you have a /Home/Index page, even if it's an orphan, if you want to use Page Inspector.  Hopefully Microsoft will fix this bug soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was also seeing the object reference error, did some research and found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1894770.aspx/1?Page+Inspector+crashes+VS+2012) thread on Asp.net.

In the 3rd post down the user states that they installed [Visual Studio 2012 Web Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web) to clear up the error.  I installed this and now Page Inspector is working just fine in my mixed project.

Comment: Sadly the link http://forums.asp.net/p/1908978/5402549.aspx/1?Re+Page+Inspector+crashes+VS+2012 is now broken.

Comment: The link is now posted here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1894770.aspx/1?Page+Inspector+crashes+VS+2012

Comment: I stared at the Web Express install button for a couple of minutes before chickening out.  I have had to reinstall VS 2012 Ultimate and all the other MS tools that go with it before because of incompatibilities.  Twice.  And it took a full day each time.  So I'll wait on your suggested workaround until I get desperate.

Comment: I've updated the first link thanks to Kevin.  I have also heard that the VS SP 3 RC update fixes the issue as well but I have not verified this as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check the address bar in Page Inspector to see what parameters are being used, possibly your page doesn't render with the given URL. Also ensure that Visual Studio has the [latest updates](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

As a workaround you could try adjusting the URL in Page Inspector, so that your controller will pass data to the view that you know is working correctly.

Comment: I have the latest updates. Page Inspector hangs before there is any opportunity to see or alter the URL.  See my answer below.